# MINIO - 'expected element type <Error> but have <html>'

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, https, load-balancing, minio

I need my MinIO to run on HTTPS that running on Docker.
I'm working with an AWS machine with a Load Balancer that provides the SSL.
I have NGINX that looks like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name fake.admin.com;




location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/fake;
    ....
    sub_filter_once off;
}


location /fake2{
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/fake;
    ....
}



location /health {
     proxy_pass http://server:3000;
 }



  location /minio-console/ {
    rewrite ^/minio-console/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;

    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;

    proxy_pass http://minio_console;
}




}

server {
    listen       9000;
    listen  [::]:9000;
    server_name  fake.admin.com;
    ignore_invalid_headers off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    proxy_pass http://minio_server;
}
}



upstream minio_server {
   server minio:9000;
}

upstream minio_console {
    ip_hash;
   server minio:9001;
}
```

And my Docker Compose file looks like this:

```
minio:
    image: minio/minio
    container_name: minio
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    volumes:
        - './minio-data:/data'
    environment:
        - MINIO_ROOT_USER=minio-root-user
        - MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=minio-root-password
        - MINIO_SERVER_URL=https://fake.admin.com:9000
        - MINIO_BROWSER_REDIRECT_URL= https://fake.admin.com/minio-console/
    command: server --address 0.0.0.0:9000 --console-address 0.0.0.0:9001 /data
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
        - "9001:9001"
    networks:
      - fake_admin_net
```

However, when I go to `https://fake.admin.com/minio-console/`, the login process fails, and I get the following error:
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQZPu.jpg)